# Pyspark external table compression does not work

Tags: python, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to save an external table from PySpark in parquet format and I need
to compress it. The PySpark version I am using is 2.4.7. I am updating the table after the initial
creation and appending data in a loop manner.

So far I have set the following options:
`.config("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")  df.write.mode("append").format("parquet").option("compression","snappy").saveAsTable(...) df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("compression","snappy").saveAsTable(...)` 
Is there anything else that I need to set or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you